# How to print without having newline added automatically at the end?

Tags: printing

```
Print["first part of the result", DateString[]]   
Print["addition to the result", DateString[]]
```

will add a newline character at the end of line automatically for each `Print[]`.  But I'd like the two strings to be shown on the same line.  How can I do this?

Comment: Some users might find [`PrintTemporary`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrintTemporary.html) useful: the printed stuff disappears when the computation is over.

Comment: Not what I asked for.

Comment: That's why I did not answer and specified it could be useful to _some_ users... The accepted answer only works with strings, not graphics. PrintTemporary at least works with graphics.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For Example:

```
WriteString["stdout", "First part of the result: ", DateString[]];
(*Perform some calc*)
i = 0;
WriteString["stdout", " -- Addition to the result: ", DateString[],  "\n"];
```

> First part of the result: Thu 15 Oct 2015 12:58:29 -- Addition to the result: Thu 15 Oct 2015 12:58:29

Comment: What's so special about the string `"stdout"`?  I would have thought such thing should be a `System\`` symbol.

Comment: Another question is is there a solution using `Print[]` instead of `WriteString[]`?

Comment: +1. As I understand, "printing" in such a way is only possible in the plaintext format?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Yep. From the help: _The special stream "stdout" allows you to give output to the "standard output" provided by the operating system. Note however that you can use this stream only with simple text-based interfaces to Mathematica._

Comment: @MaThEmAtika Print[] is a special case of CellPrint[], which creates a new cell upon each call. I can't find a way to prevent that happening.

Comment: This should probably read "\n", right?

Comment: @sebhofer good catch!

Comment: Do the documentation have no this usage?Or the `channel` in `WriteString[channel,"string"]` cantain what options?

Comment: documentation of this is not very detailed, actually I think (no reference at hand) that `"stdout"` is just a shortcut for `Streams["stdout"]` at that position, which will give you those of all open `Streams[]` which are called "stdout". `Print` will print to `$Output` which is a list of `OutputStreams`, by default having one entry which is once more `"stdout"`. So using `$Output` would probably most closely reflect the behavior of `Print`....

Answer (score 6):

I tried belisarius' answer using `WriteString`, but it just prints plain text, and you can't print, for example x<sup>2</sup>. Instead you have to print x^2 which is not cool for reading.

I found a way using Google and Mathematica's help. The main thing I was missing was that under each command found in the help of Mathematica you have "More Information" image which if clicked shows more info about the command. For the `Print` command, it says that `Print` uses the `Row` which is what I use for my solution.

The idea is to create a list. We can do it for example with the command `myArray = Range[2];`. Then instead of printing what we want to print we will add it in the list `myArray[[1]] = "First thing to print";`. When we are ready and want to print all we just call the `Row[myArray]` command which will concatenate the elements of the list and print them with a newline at the end of the concatenated elements.

**Here is your solution:**

```
myArray = Range[2];
myArray[[1]] = "first part of the result "  DateString[];
myArray[[2]] = " addition to the result "  DateString[];
Row[myArray]
```

Comment: Instead of multiplying two strings, you should probably `Join` them. In infix notation this would be `"first part"<>DateString[]`.
Also, if I understand correctly, the OP wants to use the print statements in two different locations in the code, so this won't help. It might come in handy in other situations though!

Comment: I believe you missed a point here. In the question, the need for **two** print statements comes from the fact that they are different events in time.You should be able to print something, then calculate whatever you need and then print again in the same line as before