# Concatenate string with the value of each element of a vector/list

Tags: procedural-programming, string-manipulation

I have a vector/list `t = {4, 5, 6}`. I want to output each element (its value) of `t` in a string of characters. For example, the string "Test: " concatenated with each element of `t` separated by a comma and space. Hence the output should be: `Test: 4, 5, 6`.

I tried:

- `"Test: " <> ToString[Do[j, {j, t}]]` and `"Test:" <> ToString[Do[t[[j]], {j, Length[t]}]]`, but neither outputs the elements of `t`, and both add `Null` after "Test: ".
- `"Test: " <> ToString[Do[Print[j], {j, t}]]` but it outputs the elements in different lines before "Test: ", and adds `Null` after "Test: ".

I know the code should be very easy, but I don't know how nor I found similar questions.

#### Edit

Using the code in **[this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4603/71575)**, I achieved what I wanted. The actual code is:

```
WriteString["stdout", "Test: ", t[[1]]];
Do[WriteString["stdout", ", ", t[[k]]], {k, 2, Length[t] - 1}];
WriteString["stdout", ", ", t[[Length[t]]], ".\n"];
```

#### Edit 2

Using a code by someone who deleted his comment, and slightly modifying it, we also achieved what I wanted:

```
"Test: " <> StringJoin[Table[ToString[t[[j]]] <> ", ", {j, Length[t] - 1}]] <> ToString[t[[Length[t]]]] <> "."
```

Comment: `"Test: " <> StringRiffle[t, ", "]`?

Comment: @MarcoB That worked, thanks!